# How to Create Individual YouTube API Keys for Users in a React Website

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I have a website that uses the YouTube API, and I am looking for a solution to generate unique API keys for each individual user upon login, so as to prevent multiple users from utilizing a single key. Is there a feasible way to achieve this, or is there a more effective approach to consider?

I am not sure how to approach this issue as I do not have enough information or context about the problem.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because there's a quota for the maximum number of API calls and I think if every user had his own quota there will be no need for paying for extra quota.

Comment: What I think is, your website should be the client to Youtube and the users are your clients. So you should have an API key from Youtube for your website (may be infinite request-production scope) and then your users can create your "subscription" and have their Keys for your website

Comment: If your website is generating enough traffic to go over the free quota, then you will need to pay Google more money for more usage. Any attempt to get around this will most likely violate service terms.

Comment: I agree with you, but I want to know how would I create their subscription and have their Keys?

Comment: @damonholden Oh, I didn't know that thank you, but wouldn't that make the entire service paid? as some won't be able to use the service unless an extra quota is paid?

Comment: I was incorrect about paying for more usage. Follow this link to youtube API docs for more information: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits#:~:text=If%20you%20would%20like%20to,API%20Services%20Terms%20of%20Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating additional api keys is not the solution to your issue.

Each application you create should have two projects on google cloud console.

1. Development
2. Production

You should then create a single api key used by your application, and Oauth2 client credentials if you need them.

If you run out of quota you should simply fill out the [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) and request additional quota.